# What is the best way to differentiate read/unread elements in a list?

Tags: lists

I am examining a few possible ways to differentiate between unread/unvisited and read/visited elements in a list of items. Google typically uses color to do that (e.g. Gmail), while Apple would occasionally use a little colored sphere/dot to highlight unread/unvisited items. Which is better and why? Any other common solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to show unread items in bold, and read items in its normal weight. How you do it doesn't matter as much as whether or not you are able to effectively convey the difference between what was read and unread.

Comment: The common theme between these seems to be that unread items have additional emphasis, which makes sense as they are usually more important to the user than read ones.